# how to change nowrap text by using Material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, nowrap

I want to show nowrap text like ...더보기 not ...,
how can i change it by using material-ui

```
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 500,
  },
});

export default function Types() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography noWrap variant="body1" gutterBottom>
        body1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos blanditiis teneturunde suscipit, quam beatae rerum inventore consectetur, neque doloribus, cupiditate numquam dignissimos laborum fugiat deleniti? Eum quasi quidem quibusdam.
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

it shows like that "body1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos blandit..."

but i want to show like that "body1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos blandit ...더보기"

could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the 'text-overflow' CSS property to your custom string.

You can use Material-UI's CSS overrides and use the 'noWrap' key to target that specific behavior:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 500,
  },
  noWrap: {
    textOverflow: "'...더보기'",
  },
});

export default function Types() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography classes={{ noWrap: classes.noWrap }} noWrap variant="body1" gutterBottom>
        body1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos blanditiis teneturunde suscipit, quam beatae rerum inventore consectetur, neque doloribus, cupiditate numquam dignissimos laborum fugiat deleniti? Eum quasi quidem quibusdam.
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**It turns out setting the 'text-overflow' CSS property to a custom string [is only supported in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Browser_compatibility)**

[This codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-bj8kf) will display the custom ellipsis in Firefox, but in Chrome the text-overflow CSS property will be tagged as 'invalid property value'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't works. it also show ...

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-befn3

Comment: Three things were amiss: 1. the most important, 'text-overflow' set to a custom string is only supported in Firefox, 2. I had forgotten to put a set of extra quotes around the custom string in the style definition, and 3. you forgot to add the 'noWrap' style class to the Typography component. See updated answer for details. I'm afraid the only workaround is programmatic, meaning you'll have to manipulate the string yourself.